# Combining jQuery plugin files generates errors

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, minimize

I am combining plugin files to reduce the number of HTTP requests. Removed minimization for debugging.

The combined script file is:

test.js:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
    GetNewDiv: function(){
        return $('<div>Testing new div</div');
    }
    });
})(jQuery)

// ;jQuery.noConflict(); 
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
    GetNewSpan: function(){
        return $('<span class="test">Testing new div</span>');
    }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

### HTML that uses this file

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('document ready');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
test message
</body>
```

Opening the file in Firefox displays this error in Firebug

```
function ($) {$.fn.extend({GetNewDiv: function () {return $("<div>Testing new div</div");}});}(jQuery) is not a function
file:///C://js/test.js
Line 10
```

Adding "jQuery.noConflict(); " between the 2 plugin helps, but then the error changes to 
$ is not a function

Any ideas what is wrong? What is the correct way to combine multiple .js files into one file?

Thanks
Abhi

Comment: when you paste code into questions on Stackoverflow, just paste the code, select it, and then click the "{}" at the top of the edit box.

Comment: ah! I was trying to figure that one out. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need a semicolon between the files.  Each of those ... things is a JavaScript expression fragment. Without a semicolon, the parser thinks the expression continues.

Semicolons are *sometimes* optional in JavaScript, but when they're not, they're not.

Comment: +100k you're my personal Jhon Skeet, healed me 2 days of headache

Comment: Just great. Solved my problem too.

Comment: Excelent. Solved my problem as well!